# What do i provide my graphic designer with so they can do their job?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-production, apparel

I am hiring a graphic designer to illustrate my bikini designs in Adobe Illustrator or any alternative software that works for them, so I can send the digital designs to manufacturers to produce the physical product.

What do I need to provide my graphic designer with, so they can accurately recreate my print designs?

Do I just simply send them photos of my amateur designs? Do I need to send them exact life size measurements? Do I implicate the wiring and certain details of the bikinis? Do they need color schemes if I want them in color, do they need to illustrate the same bikini in all 4 different sizes from XS-L?

Comment: If you're paying them as a professional graphic designer, expect them to tell you what they need. It's ok to sound amateur, that's what you're paying them to remedy! :)

Comment: More is usually better too. I usually tell people to just send me what they have, and I'll sift through it. It's a process, there should be good back and forth from them and you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For the production specifications you should provide your designer with descriptions, photos and sketches if you have them, along with flat patterns for every size, specific measurements for each size, material indications (where the wire goes, how thick the hems are, how long the ties are etc.), in short All the info the clothing manufacturers will need to produce them.

If you don't have the flat patterns your designer may be able to create them from the specifications but you should not expect them to make usable production templates without all the material and size information. If you have finished bikinis you should send those to your designer so they can take apart the seams, lay them flat, measure everything and draw them up to scale.

Once you have working templates for each size you can indicate different color patterns to the manufacturers.

If you leave any aspects of design up to the production people than it may come out wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your *designer* and your *printer* should be able to guide you through this:

- an apparel production **company** will probably have their own technical specs and/or sizing templates they can provide you with for each size (XS, S, M, L, etc). Starting without these could probably force your designer to re-adjust the artwork at a later stage.
- your **designer** should see your current artwork (drawings, sketches, photos, etc) and tell you what other material should be needed to complete the processing of these. You should expect a few rounds of revisions to get the designs close to what you need.

Comment: This answer is not specific to garment production.  Leaving it to the apparel production company to use their own template for bikinis is not designing.

Comment: Why not. What I meant was a _sizing_ or _cut-out_ template. You can't just assume what the exact measurement are for XS, S, M, L, etc. These are probably standardized and you need to follow some guidelines when designing the artwork - http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0052/4432/files/IMG_3611.JPG

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's all mix. You might need to give them rough sketches/designs along with estimated measurements. Because there are 4 different sizes, you can't tell them exactly to make drawing on exactly same what you tell them. This will bound your designer's creative skills. 
Let them draw in their way but with your only guidelines. So they could produce illustrations living within the boundaries but still with free room.

There is still no any hard and fast rule to set in that way. you simply provide them photos of your amateur designs with estimated sizes for S, M, L, XL etc. and required angles to get a preview.

Comment: This is not useful to the poster because production requires very specific information. If you're designing clothes and need a graphics person to translate your designs into production specs than you need very specific information about every piece of the garment.

Answer (score -1):

Tee shirt printing and graphically you need to have following

copyright images 
Trademark content writer 
good graphic combinations